# Hide child headers for grouped column - nestedTreeDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, flexicious

I have a nestedtreedatagrid with two a column group. I wish to hide the header cells for the children in this group. I want the grid to only have a single header row, rather than the default of a header row for each child level. How can I accomplish this task?

```
<nestedtreedatagrid:FlexDataGridColumnGroup headerText="header">
    <nestedtreedatagrid:columns>
        <nestedtreedatagrid:FlexDataGridColumn dataField="child1" columnWidthMode="fitToContent" >
        </nestedtreedatagrid:FlexDataGridColumn>
        <nestedtreedatagrid:FlexDataGridColumn dataField="child2" columnWidthMode="fitToContent" >
        </nestedtreedatagrid:FlexDataGridColumn>
    </nestedtreedatagrid:columns>
</nestedtreedatagrid:FlexDataGridColumnGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the current version of this grid.